# Add paginate to a inner joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

How to add paginate with a specific query?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT emptb.*, tempstore.* FROM (SELECT * FROM emptb WHERE Department = :dept)emptb inner join tempstore 
on emptb.EmpID = tempstore.EmpID WHERE tempstore.ValidDate BETWEEN DATE(:fromDate) AND DATE(:toDate)
```

Note: When I add a paginate, the next and previous button don't work it was stuck at the first record that it sees in the table. Can you give me some good paginate to go with this kind of query?

Comment: You have to use offset and limit in your query. It doesn't matter you have joins or not. Please share your table structures and share what you exactly want to do. I will help you.

Comment: The results that i want was to view per page the records of per employee that is emptb and their respective attendance that is tempstore. To rephrase further show every records of attendance by date per employee. I cannot put the limit in the outer query for it will show one date only but if i put the lmit in the inner query, the next and previous button don't work but i successfully show attendance per employee.

Comment: Don't use sub SELECT. Solve it with JOINs. Please share the structure, and I will help you.

Comment: In employee table it contains primary key id auto increment, employee id, lastname, firstname, department. The attendance table have id primary key auto increment, employee id, date, timein, lunchout, lunchin, timeout. How will i restructure my query to comply to the requirements of even the most pagination code. Can i replace it with union?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination works because you specify a limit to the sql clause but there is none in the above query. Also, I have found that you need to now the total number of records you could expect - hence the count!

Quick example, hope this is what you meant...

```
$pageNumber=0;
$startRow=0;
$maxRows=10;



$sql="select 
    ( 
        select count(*) from ( select * from `emptb` where `department` = :dept ) emptb 
        inner join `tempstore` on emptb.`empid` = tempstore.`empid` 
        where tempstore.`validdate`
        between date(:fromdate) and date(:todate)
    ) as 'dbrecordcount',
    emptb.*, 
    tempstore.* from ( select * from `emptb` where `department` = :dept ) emptb 
    inner join `tempstore` on emptb.`empid` = tempstore.`empid` 
    where tempstore.`validdate`
    between date(:fromdate) and date(:todate)
    limit $startRow, $maxRows;";


/* above would show the first 10 records */
-> ie: records 0,10


/* Page number is increased by 1 after clicking pagination link / button */
-> $startRow=$pageNumber * $maxRows ~ equals 10;
-> would then show records from 10,20



/* To derive the pagination links, something like this perhaps... */

/* Number of records per page */
$maxRows=10;

/* The total number of expected rows: uses db result 'dbrecordcount' */
$totalRows=$db->dbrecordcount;

/* Current page within paged results: retrieve `page` from querystring if using GET method */
$pageNumber=$_GET['page'];

/* How many pages of results are there */
$totalPages=( $maxRows > 0 ) ? abs( ceil( $totalRows / $maxRows ) - 1 ) : 0;

/* Where does paging begin */
$startRow=$pageNumber * $maxRows;

/* Display pagination links if there are sufficient number of records */
if( $totalPages > 0 && $totalRows > $maxRows ){

    /* First record link */
    if( $pageNumber==0 ) {
        echo "First";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='?page=0'>First</a>";
    }

    /* Previous record link */
    if( $pageNumber > 0 ){
        echo "<a href='?page=".max( 0, $pageNumber - 1 )."'>Previous</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Previous";
    }

    /* Next record link */
    if( ( $pageNumber + 1 ) > $totalPages ){
        echo 'Next';
    } else {
        echo "<a href='?page=".min( $totalPages, $pageNumber + 1 )."'>Next</a>";
    }

    /* Last record link */
    if( $pageNumber==$totalPages ){
        echo 'Last';
    } else {
        echo "<a href='?page=".$totalPages."'>Last</a>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I will try your solution. I have another question, is the max rows can be flexible on how many records it will handle like 1000 records?

Comment: Yep, you could set the maxrows to whatever number you wanted - though displaying 1000 records per page might take a while to render and nobody would look at each record surely. The above is not tested but should give you a good headstart when trying to get pagination working on your pages. Good luck!

Comment: lets say i have 1000 rows from search result and the HR manager wants to see every employee record per page. How will i do that?

Comment: ? if there are a total of 1000 rows and he wants to see all of them, at once, then you don't need pagination. If there are more than 1000 rows in total and he wants to see 1000 rows per page set `$maxRows=1000`

Comment: I forgot to ask why did you put the limit at the outer query it will result to show only one date record of lets say january per employee not the whole record of january per employee?